# how to Insert and echo checkboxes with Php mysql and mamp

Tags: php, mysql, html, mamp, checkbox

I'm really struggling with getting checkboxes to work, I've looked up tutorials
and have found no help... I'm not sure how to set up my table in MAMP for checkboxes and how to insert it...

If some one could help that would be just fantastic guys...

HTML:

```
<form action="mainpage2.php" method="POST">
  Search : <input type="text" name="firstname" id="name" />
  <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Submit" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="tick[]" value="male" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="tick[]" value="female" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="tick[]" value="alien" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
    $subject = $_POST['firstname']; 
    $subjec = $_POST['tick']; 
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO chipsticks (Name,sports) VALUES ('$subject'),('subjec');",$database);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to flatten the array in order to store it in database.

```
if(isset($_POST['confirm']))
{
    $subject = $_POST['firstname']; 
    $subjec = $_POST['tick']; 

    $sports = '';
    if(is_array($subjec) && count($subjec)>0)
    {
        $sports = implode(',',$subjec);
    }

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO chipsticks (Name,sports) VALUES ('$subject','$sports')",$database);
}
```

Instead of implode, you can also use `serialize`